# iphone home button event

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am developing a iPhone application and would need to track the home button pressed event by user while the app is in background mode.I have  go through the apple documentation/apis but could not find out any to track.

It would be great if anyone can help me on this to track the iPhone home button pressed event.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this, that will make a difference in a possible solution

Answer (score 5):

Your application can't catch any events while in the background. There are some special cases which allows your app to do some tasks in the background, but even them wouldn't allow you to listen to Home button interaction.

Answer (score 0):

You cann't track the home button pressed or not but as your situation is to see if application went in background or not. for this there is a method **applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application**. This method is called as the application enters into background.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
NSLog(@"Application Entered Into Background.");
}
```